# Have I correctly used currency conversion

Tags: arithmetic, finance

Please can you help me with this question? I think I have the right answer but I want to make sure.

The question asks: JPY 1,000 in Year 1 is worth how many US dollars in Year 1?

Assume

> Value of 1 Euro (Euro)
>   For Year 1
>   US Dollar = 1.60
>   JPY = 158
>
> Choices
>
> - A) USD 12.83
> - B) USD 10.13
> - C) USD 14.05
> - D) USD 12.83
> - E) USD 6.33

The way I have done it is...

$1.60 / 158 = 0.010126582$

$0.010126582 \times 1000 = 10.12658228 = \mathrm{USD} 10.13 \text{ (Answer is B)}$

Is this the correct? Thanks in advance for your valuable help.

Comment: May I ask what makes you unsure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes; since 1€ = 158¥, to go from 1000 ¥ to euros you divide by 158. Then, since 1€ = $\$$1.60, to go from euros to dollars you multiply by 1.60. So to go from yen to dollars, you multiply by $\frac{1.6}{158}$. So the total is
$$1000\text{ yen} = 1000\left(\frac{1.6\text{ dollars/euro}}{158\text{ yen/euro}}\right) \approx 10.13\text{ dollars}.$$

Comment: Thank you for your swift resonse.